# How to improve a simple LIKE on large tables

Tags: mysql, performance, like

I have a business facing web application that runs on MySQL that runs a query like this on certain pages.

```
SELECT event_user, event_type, event_details
FROM `event_history` 
WHERE `event_details` 
LIKE '%keyword%' 
ORDER BY `event_history_id` 
DESC;
```

That table is now at 300,000 records and growing.

Is it possible to improve the performance of this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leading "%" in the query disables use of indexes. This will cause performance to continue to decline as you accumulate more data.

You may want to consider want to consider using a FULLTEXT index with appropriate syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the leading % makes things tricky, but if the event_details field contains a list of delimited items and you are searching for one of those items then you could create a child table event_history_details that contains one row for each item in the event_details field for each event.

Such a setup would scale well and be SARGable. Unfortunately it involves changing more than just the query.